# Create a partial distance matrix in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I would like to calculate the straight distances between a series of points:
in the first layer (rows) there are the locations of the domicile of my respondents;
in the second layer (columns) there are the locations of supermarkets that each respondent said he/she attends.

For example, respondent 1 is associated to two supermarkets (it means he/she usually attends two supermarkets).
As for me it is relevant to know the distance between each respondent and the supermarkets he/she attends, I don't need to calculate the all distances between each respondent and each possible supermarket.
Is there a way to account this issue in the Distance Matrix available in QGIS? Alternatively, can I use another tool to make this calculation? 
The drawback of the "complete" Distance Matrix is that it contains in my case lots of information and it is not very handy to consult.

Comment: It will assist if you can put in an example of the file structure for each of the layers. For example, how is the information on shopping centre attendance stored- in multiple fields or in one? Also specify for each user who attends more than one shopping centre whether you want the average distance or the total distance.